# PostgreSQL sequence not rolling back in Node.js application despite transaction rollback

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, backend, pg

I'm encountering an issue in my Node.js application where the PostgreSQL sequence (nextval) continues to increment even if there is an error during validation or insertion, and I have explicitly rolled back the transaction. The application uses Node.js with the pg library and the pool connection. Below is a simplified version of the relevant code:

```
// userController.js
const pool = require('../db/pool');
const userSchema = require('../schemas/userSchema');

const addUser = async (full_name, phone_number, password) => {
  const client = await pool.connect();

  try {
    // Start a transaction
    await client.query('BEGIN');

    // Validate input data using Zod
    const userData = userSchema.parse({ full_name, phone_number, password });

    // Insert data into the users table
    const query = `
      INSERT INTO users (full_name, phone_number, password)
      VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
      RETURNING *;
    `;

    const values = [userData.full_name, userData.phone_number, userData.password];

    const result = await client.query(query, values);

    // Commit the transaction
    await client.query('COMMIT');

    // Return the newly created user
    return result.rows[0];
  } catch (error) {
    // Roll back the transaction in case of an error
    await client.query('ROLLBACK');
    console.error('Error adding user:', error);
    throw error; // Rethrow the error to be caught by the calling code
  } finally {
    client.release(); // Release the client back to the pool
  }
};

module.exports = {
  addUser,
};
```

[image: Table Structure]

Despite the rollback in the catch block, the sequence continues to increment if there is an error during insertion. I suspect it might be a PostgreSQL-specific behavior. Any insights into why this might be happening or suggestions for an alternative approach would be greatly appreciated.

**Additional Information:**

1. Node.js version: [ 18.19.1 ]
2. PostgreSQL version: [ PostgreSQL 16.2 ]
3. pg library version: [ 8.11.3 ]
4. Operating System: [ macOS Monterey ]

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: From the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html): "Because nextval and setval calls are never rolled back, sequence objects cannot be used if “gapless” assignment of sequence numbers is needed." [Also](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) "To avoid blocking concurrent transactions that obtain numbers from the same sequence, the value obtained by nextval is not reclaimed for re-use if the calling transaction later aborts. This means that transaction aborts or database crashes can result in gaps in the sequence of assigned values."

Comment: So it's by design. The same thing happens in SQL Server and probably most other DBMSs. See also https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/gaps-in-sequences-postgresql/